# ExpressJS - All Route Pattern Generates Redirect Loop

Tags: express

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    redirect('/register');
});

app.get('/register', function(req, res) {
    res.send('This is register page');
});
```

This code generates redirect loop. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `*` matches `/register` too.

Routes are processed in the order you declare them; if you change the order so `/register` is matched first, it should work:

```
app.get('/register', function(req, res) {
  res.send('This is register page');
});

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/register');
});
```

Comment: Do you mean * matches /register instead of /redirect? Is it typo?

Comment: It works. .all('*') also matches /register. Never thought about it. Thank you.

Comment: @KurniawanJunaidy sorry about the typo, fixed my answer :)